# Order by not-selected column

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, contains, containstable

I'm trying to use the SQL operator `CONTAINSTABLE` to get a list of search results, like this:

```
SELECT c.*, ccontains.[RANK]
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Customers, LastName, @searchTerm) ccontains ON c.Id = ccontains.[KEY]
```

And calling this function from EF Core 2.1:

```
var query = DbContext.Customers.FromSql("SELECT * FROM udfSearchCustomers(@searchTerm)",
    new SqlParameter(@searchTerm, mySearchTerm));
query = query.Include(c => c.Addresses).Take(maxResults);
```

I want to order my search results descending by `RANK`, to get the most relevant results at the top. Adding an `ORDER BY ccontains.[RANK]` to my function is not allowed, as my `SELECT * FROM udfSearchCustomers(...)` will be wrapped by EF Core: `ORDER BY` is not allowed on an inner query. Adding `query.OrderBy(c => c.Rank)` is not possible, as `RANK` is not on the `Customer` entity.

I've tried using `System.Linq.Dynamic`, as well as other reflection solutions, to do this:

```
query = query.OrderBy("Rank");
```

But I got an exception:

> "Rank" is not a member of type "Customer"

which is true. Is there any way to order on a column not on an entity, or will I need to create a `MyCustomerSearchQuery` query object and use AutoMapper to convert those to `Customer`? I'd rather not, as `Customer` has many properties and keeping those in sync will be a hassle.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
 query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Rank);
```

OR

```
 query = query.OrderBy(x => x["Rank"]);
```

Comment: Alas, `Rank` is not a property on `Customer`, so this does not compile

Comment: can you create 1 new modal. this modal inherit customer class and also create Rank property. sett this modal return type

Comment: Also tried that :) EF Core rejects this new class, saying query objects and entities may not be in the same inheritance tree.

Comment: best way you can call stored procedure and return result

Answer (score 0):

You can create the stored procedure of the query which takes two parameter : @searchKey, @orderByColumn.

```
      CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UdfSearchCustomers]
                 @searchTerm varchar(50),
                 @orderByColumn varchar(50)

          AS
          BEGIN
          DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
          SET @sql =' SELECT c.*, ccontains.[RANK]
                  FROM Customers c
                  INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Customers, LastName, ''@searchTerm'') ccontains 
                  ON c.Id = ccontains.[KEY]
                  ORDER BY @orderByColumn'

            SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@orderByColumn', @orderByColumn)
            SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@searchTerm', @searchTerm)
            exec sp_executesql @sql
            END

    GO
```

Then you can query the same stored procedure as:

```
var query = DbContext.Customers.FromSql("exec UdfSearchCustomers @p0, @p1", mySearchTerm, "Rank");
```

If you want to add join to the address table  then you can add the join to the stored procedure. This may give you your desired result.